# Lighttpd SSI: Setting variable to value of HTTP_ACCEPT

Tags: server, lighttpd, ssi, shtml

I am using this shtml file for testing.

```
<!--#set var="lemon" value="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#echo var="lemon" -->
<!--#include virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#include file="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#fsize virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#flastmod virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
```

This echoes the value stored in the variable lemon, but the variable lemon does not have the value of HTTP_ACCEPT. How do I fix this?

I have tried it like this too.

```
<!--#set var="lemon" value="$HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#echo var="lemon" -->
<!--#include virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#include file="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#fsize virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
<!--#flastmod virtual="HTTP_ACCEPT" -->
```

Answer (score 1):

see wikipedia: [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

`<!--#echo var="HTTP_ACCEPT"-->`

Comment: This works. 
But when I try to do something similar to the variable. Instead of it storing the value of HTTP_ACCEPT, it stores the string HTTP_ACCEPT

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation [lighttpd mod_ssi documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSSI) and then trying to find an alternate route to do whatever it is you are trying to do.  Server-Side-Includes offers a very limited set of options.  A full scripting language allows much more.